# FOSCKEditorBundle not working only in English, not in private mode, focus on text not working

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I've got a really weird bug with CKEditor 4, so:

I use this bundle:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/index.html

I have a multilanguage system and the bundle with CKEditor works fine on `/fr`, `/se`, `/de` but not in `/en`.

I have nothing special on the route `/en`.

The problem is on `/en` the editor is not focusable, when I click inside nothing append. When I check the element with the console, I can see on the iframe a `class=display:none !important`, And I can't remove this class, think it's from `ckeditor.js`.

I try everything, clear all cache (sf/browser) , remove all js's, css etc ...

Nothing works.

Which is very weird, it's working in private mode in English?

I don't known how to fix this bug.

If someone got an idea?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working? And please do not use useless tags - this question is in no way related to "mode"

Comment: i've updated my post, sry for bad tags

Comment: So if you open a private browser session it works, but if you clear your browser's cache and try in a non-private session it does not work? What if you clear your cookies as well?

Comment: Yes i clear every cache possible but it doesnt work :(